# client server using fifos, sending burst and receiving processing time

Tags: c, server, client, fifo

Good evening people. I've been working on this code that sends a burst on the client side as well as the private fifo name over a struct, to a server which will process several clients and the burst time that will be sent back to the client through the private fifo.

The issue is that once I enter the burst on the client side, it won't send the proper burst to the server, which in turn it will read the private fifo name but not the burst, since there is no burst (and the server has a set burst entered by the user), the actual burst will become a giantnumber.

I'm attaching my code hoping than maybe another pair of eyes can see where I am getting my mistake and help me to correct it. Thanks

client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



typedef struct values {
     char name[30];
     int arrivalTime;
     int burst;           //used for both the initial size of the process and to send the completion time
} Process;  /*Datatype of the elements in the queue*/


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){

    Process process;

    int fdIN; //to write to character server
    int fdOUT; //to read from character server
    int clientID;

    clientID = getpid();
    sprintf(process.name, "FIFO_%d", clientID);
    printf("\nFIFO name is %s ", process.name);

  if((mkfifo(process.name, 0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
      perror("Can't create private FIFO\n");
      exit(-1);

    }

    printf("\nEnter burst: \n");

    scanf("%d", process.burst);




  if((fdIN=open("commFIFO", O_WRONLY))<0)  //writting into fifo
     printf("cant open fifo to write");

     write(fdIN, &process, sizeof(process));


  if((fdOUT=open(process.name, O_RDONLY))<0) //reading from fifo
     printf("cant open fifo to read");


  read(fdOUT, &process, sizeof(process));

  printf("\n arrival time: %d \n", process.arrivalTime);

  unlink ("commFIFO");
  unlink (process.name);

  close(fdIN);
  close(fdOUT);

}
```

my input for the client:

```
FIFO name is FIFO_24494
Enter burst:
3
```

server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



//Inbox/Outbox structure
typedef struct values {
     char name[30];
     int arrivalTime;
     int burst;           //used for both the initial size of the process and to send the completion time
} Process;


//Node definition
typedef struct node{                         /*Nodes stored in the linked list*/
        struct values request;
        struct node *next;
} Node;


//Queue Definition
typedef struct queue{                     /*A struct facilitates passing a queue as an argument*/
        Node *head;                       /*Pointer to the first node holding the queue's data*/
        Node *tail;                       /*Pointer to the last node holding the queue's data*/
        int sz;                           /*Number of nodes in the queue*/
} Queue;


int size( Queue *Q ){
        return Q->sz;
}


int isEmpty( Queue *Q ){
        if( Q->sz == 0 ) return 1;
        return 0;
}


void enqueue( Queue *Q, struct values elem ){
        Node *v = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));/*Allocate memory for the Node*/
        if( !v ){
                printf("ERROR: Insufficient memory\n");
                return;
        }
        v->request = elem;
        v->next = NULL;
        if( isEmpty(Q) ) Q->head = v;
        else Q->tail->next = v;
        Q->tail = v;
        Q->sz++;
}


struct values dequeue( Queue *Q ){
        Node *oldHead;
        struct values temp;
        if( isEmpty(Q) ){
                printf("ERROR: Queue is empty\n");
                return temp;
        }
        oldHead = Q->head;
        temp = Q->head->request;  //72
        Q->head = Q->head->next;
        free(oldHead);
        Q->sz--;
        return temp;
}


void requeue(Queue *Q, int t){
        Process temp = dequeue(Q);
        temp.burst -= t;
        enqueue(Q, temp);
}


struct values first( Queue *Q ){
        if( isEmpty(Q) ){
                printf("ERROR: Queue is empty\n");
                return Q->head->request;
        }
        return Q->head->request;
}

int *getBurst(struct values r){
        return &r.burst;
}

void setBurst(struct values *r, int a){
        r->burst = a;
}


char *getName(struct values r){
        return r.name;
}

void destroyQueue( Queue *Q ){
        while( !isEmpty(Q) ) dequeue(Q);
}

void checkNew( Queue *Q, Queue *R, int c ){
         if (!isEmpty(Q)){
                struct values temp1 = first(Q);
                if(temp1.arrivalTime <= c){
                      struct values temp2 = dequeue(Q);
                      enqueue( R, temp2 );
                      printf("NEW process arrived at %d time!!!\n", c);
                }
         }
         else{
               printf("\nNot yet\n");
         }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////MAIN///////////////////////////

main (void)
{
     int fdIN;          //common fifo file descriptor
     int fdOUT;         //private FIFOs' file desriptors
     int finish;        //status of fifos
     int count;         //Total number of clients, set by user
     int clock = 0;     //System Clock
     int i = 0;         //Iterative counter used for each section
     int timeQuaint;    //Size of clock burst, set by user
     int turnaround = 0;     //will store total turnaround time to calculate the average at the end

     Process process;

     /*Declare a queue and initialize its fields*/
     Queue Ready;
     Ready.head = NULL;
     Ready.tail = NULL;
     Ready.sz = 0;

     /*Declare a queue and initialize its fields*/
     Queue notArrived;
     notArrived.head = NULL;
     notArrived.tail = NULL;
     notArrived.sz = 0;


    //Prep commFIFO for clients
    if ((mkfifo("commFIFO",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))         /*Creating commFIFO*/
    {
        perror("Can't create Common FIFO\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////All variables defined and commFIFO open for clients
////////////////////////////UI & Enqueueing////////////////

    //User Promts
    printf("How many clients do you have? (Max of 10.)\n");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    int finalTimes[count];

    printf("How big is the server's burst?\n");
    scanf("%d", &timeQuaint);


    if((fdIN=open("commFIFO", O_RDONLY))<0)                       /*Opening commFIFO*/
        printf("Can't open common FIFO to read\n");

    //Read from clients
    int totalBurst =0; //will store total of burst from requests for final reporting
    while( i < count)                                               //For each process
     {
          printf("\nWaiting for client request...\n\n");

          read(fdIN, &process, sizeof(process));
          printf("The size is %d\n", process.burst);
          printf("The Private FIFO name is %s.\n", process.name);
          int b = process.burst;

          totalBurst = b + totalBurst;
                                  //added for reporting

          //Assign process to Ready or notArrived
          if(process.arrivalTime > 0){
                    printf("This process has not yet arrived.\n\n");
                    enqueue(&notArrived, process);
          }
          else{
                    enqueue(&Ready, process);
          }
          i++;
          printf("\nSize of Ready queue: %d\nSize of notArrived queue: %d\n\n", Ready.sz, notArrived.sz);
     }
     printf("\nTotal Bursts: %d\n", totalBurst);
     //Close commFIFO
     close(fdIN);
     unlink("commFIFO");
     printf("commFIFO closed and unlinked.\n\n");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////All user requests queued
////////////////////////////BODY///////////////////////Queue begins to roll
     i = 0;
     while( !isEmpty(&Ready) || !isEmpty(&notArrived)){
         if(!isEmpty(&Ready)){
              printf("\n\n%d  = qSize\n\nHead timeRemaining: %d\n", Ready.sz, *getBurst(first(&Ready)));

              //Return Data to each client
              if(*getBurst(first(&Ready)) > timeQuaint || isEmpty(&Ready)){    //If there is more process left then 1 burst or Ready Queue is empty
                  clock += timeQuaint;

                  checkNew( &notArrived, &Ready, clock );                       //new line to check for new process
                  requeue(&Ready, timeQuaint);
              }
              else{
                  process = first(&Ready);
                  printf("Item dequeued.\n%s\n\n", process.name);
                  clock += *getBurst(first(&Ready));
                  process.burst = clock;                                     //reset burst as completion time
                  process.arrivalTime = clock  - process.arrivalTime;
                  turnaround += process.arrivalTime;
                  finalTimes[i] = clock;
                  i++;
                  dequeue(&Ready);
                  checkNew( &notArrived, &Ready, clock );                          //new line to check for new process
                  printf("YAY\n");
                  printf("A Process(%s) has finished at: %d time units\n\n", process.name, clock);
                  fdOUT = open(process.name, O_WRONLY);             //Open privFIFO
                  write(fdOUT, &process, sizeof(process));          //Write to privFIFO
              }
          }
        else{
              clock += 1;
              checkNew( &notArrived, &Ready, clock);
        }
     }//END QUEUE
     destroyQueue(&Ready);
     destroyQueue(&notArrived);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////All processes have been exhausted and Queue is empty
/////////////////Post Queue Reporting///////////////////

     i = 0;
     int x = 0;


     while(i < count){
          if(x< finalTimes[i]&&x<250){
               printf("*");
               x++;
          }
          else{
               printf("Client Complete@%d", finalTimes[i]);
               i++;
          }
     }//END printing WHILE
     printf("\nNew PRINT");
     int t = turnaround/count;
     int u = finalTimes[count-1];
     printf("\n\nAverage Turnaround Time: %d\n\nCPU Utilization: %d/%d\n", t, totalBurst, u);
}
```

the input and outcome from the server:

```
How many clients do you have? (Max of 10.)
1
How big is the server's burst?
5

Waiting for client request...

The size is 134615364
The Private FIFO name is FIFO_24494.
This process has not yet arrived.


Size of Ready queue: 0
Size of notArrived queue: 1


Total Bursts: 134615364
commFIFO closed and unlinked.
```

at this point I canceled the program with a ctrl + C to cancel the recurring burst in reversive count.

Again any help or suggestion is well received. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake, and I hope this might help anyone else in the future, the only missing thing was a small & (ampersand).

client:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



typedef struct values {
     char name[30];
     int arrivalTime;
     int burst;           //used for both the initial size of the process and to send the completion time
} Process;  /*Datatype of the elements in the queue*/


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){

    Process process;

    int fdIN; //to write to character server
    int fdOUT; //to read from character server
    int clientID;

    clientID = getpid();
    sprintf(process.name, "FIFO_%d", clientID);
    printf("\nFIFO name is %s ", process.name);

  if((mkfifo(process.name, 0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))
    {
      perror("Can't create private FIFO\n");
      exit(-1);

    }

    printf("\nEnter burst: \n");

    scanf("%d", &process.burst);




  if((fdIN=open("commFIFO", O_WRONLY))<0)  //writting into fifo
     printf("cant open fifo to write");

     write(fdIN, &process, sizeof(process));


  if((fdOUT=open(process.name, O_RDONLY))<0) //reading from fifo
     printf("cant open fifo to read");


  read(fdOUT, &process, sizeof(process));

  printf("\n arrival time: %d \n", process.arrivalTime);

  unlink ("commFIFO");
  unlink (process.name);

  close(fdIN);
  close(fdOUT);

}
```

server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>



//Inbox/Outbox structure
typedef struct values {
     char name[30];
     int arrivalTime;
     int burst;           //used for both the initial size of the process and to send the completion time
} Process;


//Node definition
typedef struct node{                         /*Nodes stored in the linked list*/
        struct values request;
        struct node *next;
} Node;


//Queue Definition
typedef struct queue{                     /*A struct facilitates passing a queue as an argument*/
        Node *head;                       /*Pointer to the first node holding the queue's data*/
        Node *tail;                       /*Pointer to the last node holding the queue's data*/
        int sz;                           /*Number of nodes in the queue*/
} Queue;


int size( Queue *Q ){
        return Q->sz;
}


int isEmpty( Queue *Q ){
        if( Q->sz == 0 ) return 1;
        return 0;
}


void enqueue( Queue *Q, struct values elem ){
        Node *v = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));/*Allocate memory for the Node*/
        if( !v ){
                printf("ERROR: Insufficient memory\n");
                return;
        }
        v->request = elem;
        v->next = NULL;
        if( isEmpty(Q) ) Q->head = v;
        else Q->tail->next = v;
        Q->tail = v;
        Q->sz++;
}


struct values dequeue( Queue *Q ){
        Node *oldHead;
        struct values temp;
        if( isEmpty(Q) ){
                printf("ERROR: Queue is empty\n");
                return temp;
        }
        oldHead = Q->head;
        temp = Q->head->request;  //72
        Q->head = Q->head->next;
        free(oldHead);
        Q->sz--;
        return temp;
}


void requeue(Queue *Q, int t){
        Process temp = dequeue(Q);
        temp.burst -= t;
        enqueue(Q, temp);
}


struct values first( Queue *Q ){
        if( isEmpty(Q) ){
                printf("ERROR: Queue is empty\n");
                return Q->head->request;
        }
        return Q->head->request;
}

int *getBurst(struct values r){
        return &r.burst;
}

void setBurst(struct values *r, int a){
        r->burst = a;
}


char *getName(struct values r){
        return r.name;
}

void destroyQueue( Queue *Q ){
        while( !isEmpty(Q) ) dequeue(Q);
}

void checkNew( Queue *Q, Queue *R, int c ){
         if (!isEmpty(Q)){
                struct values temp1 = first(Q);
                if(temp1.arrivalTime <= c){
                      struct values temp2 = dequeue(Q);
                      enqueue( R, temp2 );
                      printf("NEW process arrived at %d time!!!\n", c);
                }
         }
         else{
               printf("\nNot yet\n");
         }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////MAIN///////////////////////////

main (void)
{
     int fdIN;          //common fifo file descriptor
     int fdOUT;         //private FIFOs' file desriptors
     int finish;        //status of fifos
     int count;         //Total number of clients, set by user
     int clock = 0;     //System Clock
     int i = 0;         //Iterative counter used for each section
     int timeQuaint;    //Size of clock burst, set by user
     int turnaround = 0;     //will store total turnaround time to calculate the average at the end

     Process process;

     /*Declare a queue and initialize its fields*/
     Queue Ready;
     Ready.head = NULL;
     Ready.tail = NULL;
     Ready.sz = 0;

     /*Declare a queue and initialize its fields*/
     Queue notArrived;
     notArrived.head = NULL;
     notArrived.tail = NULL;
     notArrived.sz = 0;


    //Prep commFIFO for clients
    if ((mkfifo("commFIFO",0666)<0 && errno != EEXIST))         /*Creating commFIFO*/
    {
        perror("Can't create Common FIFO\n");
        exit(-1);
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////All variables defined and commFIFO open for clients
////////////////////////////UI & Enqueueing////////////////

    //User Promts
    printf("How many clients do you have? (Max of 10.)\n");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    int finalTimes[count];

    printf("How big is the server's burst?\n");
    scanf("%d", &timeQuaint);


    if((fdIN=open("commFIFO", O_RDONLY))<0)                       /*Opening commFIFO*/
        printf("Can't open common FIFO to read\n");

    //Read from clients
    int totalBurst =0; //will store total of burst from requests for final reporting
    while( i < count)                                               //For each process
     {
          printf("\nWaiting for client request...\n\n");

          read(fdIN, &process, sizeof(process));
          printf("The size is %d\n", process.burst);
          printf("The Private FIFO name is %s.\n", process.name);
          int b = process.burst;

          totalBurst = b + totalBurst;
                                  //added for reporting

          //Assign process to Ready or notArrived
          if(process.arrivalTime > 0){
                    printf("This process has not yet arrived.\n\n");
                    enqueue(&notArrived, process);
          }
          else{
                    enqueue(&Ready, process);
          }
          i++;
          printf("\nSize of Ready queue: %d\nSize of notArrived queue: %d\n\n", Ready.sz, notArrived.sz);
     }
     printf("\nTotal Bursts: %d\n", totalBurst);
     //Close commFIFO
     close(fdIN);
     unlink("commFIFO");
     printf("commFIFO closed and unlinked.\n\n");

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////All user requests queued
////////////////////////////BODY///////////////////////Queue begins to roll
     i = 0;
     while( !isEmpty(&Ready) || !isEmpty(&notArrived)){
         if(!isEmpty(&Ready)){
              printf("\n\n%d  = qSize\n\nHead timeRemaining: %d\n", Ready.sz, *getBurst(first(&Ready)));

              //Return Data to each client
              if(*getBurst(first(&Ready)) > timeQuaint || isEmpty(&Ready)){    //If there is more process left then 1 burst or Ready Queue is empty
                  clock += timeQuaint;

                  checkNew( &notArrived, &Ready, clock );                       //new line to check for new process
                  requeue(&Ready, timeQuaint);
              }
              else{
                  process = first(&Ready);
                  printf("Item dequeued.\n%s\n\n", process.name);
                  clock += *getBurst(first(&Ready));
                  process.burst = clock;                                     //reset burst as completion time
                  process.arrivalTime = clock  - process.arrivalTime;
                  turnaround += process.arrivalTime;
                  finalTimes[i] = clock;
                  i++;
                  dequeue(&Ready);
                  checkNew( &notArrived, &Ready, clock );                          //new line to check for new process
                  printf("YAY\n");
                  printf("A Process(%s) has finished at: %d time units\n\n", process.name, clock);
                  fdOUT = open(process.name, O_WRONLY);             //Open privFIFO
                  write(fdOUT, &process, sizeof(process));          //Write to privFIFO
              }
          }
        else{
              clock += 1;
              checkNew( &notArrived, &Ready, clock);
        }
     }//END QUEUE
     destroyQueue(&Ready);
     destroyQueue(&notArrived);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////All processes have been exhausted and Queue is empty
/////////////////Post Queue Reporting///////////////////

     i = 0;
     int x = 0;


     while(i < count){
          if(x< finalTimes[i]&&x<250){
               printf("*");
               x++;
          }
          else{
               printf("Client Complete@%d", finalTimes[i]);
               i++;
          }
     }//END printing WHILE
     printf("\nNew PRINT");
     int t = turnaround/count;
     int u = finalTimes[count-1];
     printf("\n\nAverage Turnaround Time: %d\n\nCPU Utilization: %d/%d\n", t, totalBurst, u);
}
```